# The template doesn't know if User is authenticated, why?

Tags: python, django

If i use this line of code;

```
return render_to_response('template.html',{}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

then the following will work;

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p><a href="/user/user_logout/" class="button">Logout</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

But if i add {'formUsers':formusers} like the following it doesn't work,

```
return render_to_response('template.html',{'formUsers':formUsers}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I need to add the form however the template doesn't know if User is authenticated?
Can i have both?

Comment: `{'formUsers': formUsers,'user': user}` You can add user object like this and render it in your template.

Comment: do i have to to this user = User.objects.get(user=request.user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the more common form:

`return render(request, 'template.html', { 'formUsers': formUsers } )`

that should work, then in your template do

`{% if request.user.is_authenticated %} ...`

Comment: The `request` variable won't be in the context unless `django.core.context_processors.request` is enabled. It is not enabled by default. `user` should be able by default unless something is misconfigured which is likely the case here.

Comment: didn't know user was always in context... thanks.  I must have added the request in the middleware long ago and forgot :)